# How to disable 'Ask where to save' setting in my extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a simple chrome extension to download many files at once from my school, but it ask me every time I call **chrome.downloads.download()**. The problem is I need **'Ask where to save each file before downloading'**  when download elsewhere. What should I do?

I had try to look answer in https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/downloads, but found nothing. Is there anything I ignored or wrong?

Comment: There's a `saveAs` boolean parameter in the documentation, looks like what you want.

Comment: `saveAs` is not working here. It's only useful when **Ask where to save turn off** and `saveAs=true`. How sad :(  @wOxxOm

Answer (score -1):

> > > Hello **Trevour**, I think you should disable a setting from Chrome->setting->Downloads section. Check below steps:

```
   1) On your computer, open Chrome Browser.  
   2) At the top right, click **three vertically dotted link** (:) and then Settings.  
   3) At the bottom, click **Show advanced settings**.  
   4) Under the "Downloads" section, disable the option of **Ask where to save each file before downloading**.
```

Once the option will get disabled, the downloads will get saved in the selected location.

Comment: It sound like a good practice for me, but my friends also want this extension, some of them prefer to turn this setting on. That is really a headache.

Comment: Okay @TrevorHuang , If I'll try to find a better solution...will update the answer surely. This method was just a suggestion.

Comment: Or maybe I can suggest them to disable this :)  But any solution on my side is more welcomed